# Nested loop Synchronous or Asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, nested, nonblocking

I have an array called `noNCreatedResources`. I want do some operation on each item of array and push item in `createdResources` array and remove the item from `noNCreatedResources` array and continue to do that until `noNCreatedResources` be empty. For this I've written `CreateResources` function including nested while and for loop. It works fine but i realize that it don't work synchronously. For example: it must iterate twice in while loop but iterates 4 times and I don't know why.
I think I don't understand concept of async/await/non-blocking concept of node.js. can any body help me to realize what the problem is?

```
CreateResources = async () => {
  while (this.noNCreatedResources.length > 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.noNCreatedResources.length; index++) {
      if (this.resourceHasCreatedDependencies(this.noNCreatedResources[index])) {
        const resourceModel = this.someOperation(this.noNCreatedResources[index]);
        this.createdResources.push(resourceModel);
        this.noNCreatedResources.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not doing anything asynchronous in you function so you can remove the `async` keyword from your function. Since you are not doing anything asynchronous so, your problem is not related to it. It is more of an implementation problem IMO.

Your `while` loop is useless for what you are trying to achieve. Also, your logic is broken!

**Example:** The following code will output `1`, `3`, and `5`.

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  console.log(x[i]);
  x.splice(i, 1);
}
```

I do not think you need to remove item from array to achieve your expected result. If you need to reset the array then at the end you can just do this `x = []` to reset the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not due to async calls. Actually, your code is entirely synchronous. Try to take a look at where the "noNCreatedResources" is been created/updated. Async calls happens when you're sending a http request, reading a file etc, in other words, operations that doesn't happens inside your code. It allows the code to go on, not blocking the next function calls, and when the promise is fulfilled, the callback function is invoked.